# How can I remove one of the '0' (origin label) for the given graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels

I was wondering if anyone could help me with removing the origin label(s) and putting '0' precisely in the corner position. By my understanding, it seems that we are supposed to remove these labels and add

```
extra x ticks={0},
extra x tick style={xticklabel style={anchor=northeast}},
```

but when I did it, the result had 3 labels of origin.
[image]

The following is the code that I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for tikz drawing
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} % <- for regular polygon nodes
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\usepackage[paperwidth=5in, paperheight=3.6in]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2mm, right=2mm, top=4mm, bottom=2mm}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        every pin/.style = {pin edge={Latex-,thin,black}},
        small dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.3}, E/.style={font=\small,text=Orange, sloped, pos=0.75},
        mystyle/.style={draw=red, label={#1}},
        declare function={a(\x)=50*\x;},
        ]
\begin{axis}[
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=bottom,
        grid=major,
        ylabel = $\textbf{Words typed}$,
        xlabel = $\textbf{Time in minutes}$,
        width=4.7in,height=3.3in,
        ymin=0,ymax=325,
        xmin=0,xmax=8.5,
        %grid style={dashed, line width=.2pt, draw=blue!25},
        %major grid style={line width=.3pt, draw=blue!60},
        %minor tick num=4,
        axis line style = thick,
        major tick style = thick,
        %x minor tick num=4,
        xtick distance = 1,
        %xsubticksize=1,
        %xtick={1,2,3},
        %xtick style={},
        %xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4},
        x grid style={thin, opacity=0.5},
        %extra x ticks={0},
        %extra x tick style={xticklabel style={anchor=northeast}},
        ytick distance = 50,
        %ysubticksize=1,
        %ytick={1,2,3},
        %ytick style={small},
        %ytick={0,5000,10000,15000,20000,25000},
        y grid style={thin, opacity=0.5},
        %axis lines = middle,
        %y axis line style = {ultra thick, stealth-stealth},
        %x axis line style = {ultra thick, stealth-stealth},
        %y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, scaled y ticks = false, set thousands separator={,}, set decimal separator={.},fixed, /tikz/.cd},
        %every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
        %every x tick label/.append style={anchor=north, },
        %every y tick label/.append style={anchor=east, },
        %every axis x label/.style={ at={(current axis.right of origin)}, anchor=west, font=\footnotesize, },
        %every axis y label/.style={ at={(current axis.above origin)},  anchor=south, font=\footnotesize, },
        axis on top=false,
        ]

%FUNCTION
\addplot[name path=a, ultra thick, -latex, samples=300, smooth, domain=0:6.5, red] {a(x)}  node [pos=0.9,left,red,font=\small] {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `anchor=north east` (with a space between `north` and `east`).

Comment: Thank you very much! @JasperHabicht

Comment: Is the present MWE sufficient for creating graphs for Math taught at school?

Comment: It is, but you should really only put those packages in your MWE that are really needed. You even load some packages twice, which you should really not do.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the options list of the `axis`:

```
xtick={1,...,8},                                % explicitly sets ticks 1 to 8 for x-axis
ytick={50,100,...,300},                         % explicitly sets ticks 50 to 300 for y-axis
extra x ticks={0},                                           % sets one extra tick at 0
extra x tick style={xticklabel style={anchor=north east}},   % aligns extra tick
```

In the end, your code should be something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in, paperheight=3.6in]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2mm, right=2mm, top=4mm, bottom=2mm}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={a(\x)=50*\x;},
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=bottom,
        grid=major,
        ylabel = $\textbf{Words typed}$,
        xlabel = $\textbf{Time in minutes}$,
        width=4.7in, height=3.3in,
        ymin=0, ymax=325,
        xmin=0, xmax=8.5,
        axis line style = thick,
        major tick style = thick,
        xtick distance = 1,
        x grid style={thin, opacity=0.5},
        ytick distance = 50,
        y grid style={thin, opacity=0.5},
        axis on top=false,
        xtick={1,...,8},
        ytick={50,100,...,300}, 
        extra x ticks={0},
        extra x tick style={xticklabel style={anchor=north east}}
    ]

%FUNCTION
\addplot[name path=a, ultra thick, -latex, samples=300, smooth, domain=0:6.5, red] {a(x)}  node [pos=0.9, left, red, font=\small] {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I strongly suggest that you clean up your code and remove packages that you don't need and also don't load packages twice.

To also remove the tick mark, you can use:

```
extra x tick style={xticklabel style={anchor=north east}, major tick length=0pt}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to remove the tick near zero?

Comment: You can use `extra x tick style={xticklabel style={anchor=north east}, major tick length=0pt}`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful.